# OSError: [Errno 97] when trying to run locust in Linux RHEL

Tags: python, python-3.x, locust

I did locust complete installation using `pip3 install locust`, wrote a small script to test it and I'm getting the following stack:

```py
[2022-11-06 12:02:03,635] acabista.remote.csb/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.13.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 908, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 473, in start_server
    self.server.serve_forever()
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
    self.start()
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 336, in start
    self.init_socket()
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 1545, in init_socket
    StreamServer.init_socket(self)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 180, in init_socket
    self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 192, in get_listener
    return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 284, in _tcp_listener
    sock = GeventSocket(family=family)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 133, in __init__
    self._sock = self._gevent_sock_class(family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
2022-11-06T15:02:03Z <Greenlet at 0x7f014637a180: <bound method WebUI.start_server of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x7f01463c0f70>>> failed with OSError

[2022-11-06 12:02:03,639] acabista.remote.csb/CRITICAL/locust.web: Unhandled exception in greenlet: <Greenlet at 0x7f014637a180: <bound method WebUI.start_server of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x7f01463c0f70>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 908, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 473, in start_server
    self.server.serve_forever()
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
    self.start()
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 336, in start
    self.init_socket()
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 1545, in init_socket
    StreamServer.init_socket(self)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 180, in init_socket
    self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 192, in get_listener
    return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 284, in _tcp_listener
    sock = GeventSocket(family=family)
  File "/home/acabista/Documents/python_studies/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 133, in __init__
    self._sock = self._gevent_sock_class(family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

I already tried running as

`locust -f first_locust_file.py`

and

`locust -f first_locust_file.py --master`

I don't know how to fix this error that seams to be happening in Greenlet

this is my current `pip list`

```
(env) [acabista@acabista ecomproj]$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
Brotli             1.0.9
certifi            2022.9.24
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
click              8.1.3
ConfigArgParse     1.5.3
Flask              2.2.2
Flask-BasicAuth    0.2.0
Flask-Cors         3.0.10
gevent             22.10.2
geventhttpclient   2.0.8
greenlet           2.0.0.post0
idna               3.4
importlib-metadata 5.0.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
locust             2.13.0
MarkupSafe         2.1.1
msgpack            1.0.4
pip                22.3
psutil             5.9.3
pyzmq              24.0.1
requests           2.28.1
roundrobin         0.0.4
setuptools         65.5.0
six                1.16.0
typing_extensions  4.4.0
urllib3            1.26.12
Werkzeug           2.2.2
wheel              0.37.1
zipp               3.10.0
zope.event         4.5.0
zope.interface     5.5.1
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have some special ipv4/ipv6 setup? Seems like another software had the same kind of issue and it was fixed by this code change https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/ncpa/commit/f079521d0a57d984c2caec88375286238a435f64 Maybe we need to do something similar, but with no way to reproduce it would be hard to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the answer for it in here: https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1770

To make locust run in the `http://localhost:8089/` I needed to run the command as

`locust -f first_locust_file.py --web-host localhost`